# Missing Resource in EL implementation: ???propertyNotReadable?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I'm using JSF2.1.  I don't have any jars in my WEF-INF folder.  My classpath is only referencing JSF2.1 and Java EE.  I'm using JDK1.7.

I'm getting "Missing Resource in EL implementation: ???propertyNotReadable???" when trying to test out processing GET parameters using `f:event type="preRenderComponent"`.  Right now I'm just trying to do a simple test.  My page has a lot on it, so I'm only showing the important parts here.  The part I added is the `<f:metadata>` block.  When I remove that block, the error goes away.

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
      xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html" 
      xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
      xmlns:c="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core">
<f:metadata>
   <f:viewParam name="team" value="#{appBean.team}" />
   <f:event type="preRenderComponent" listener="#{appBean.init}" />
</f:metadata>
```

In my backing bean, I have:

```
import javax.faces.bean.ManagedBean;
import javax.faces.bean.ViewScoped;

@ManagedBean
@ViewScoped
public class AppBean implements Serializable{
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1778234L;
    private Long team;

    public AppBean(){
    }

    public void init(){
        if (team != null) System.out.println(team);
        else System.out.println("team undefined");
    }

    public void setTeam(Long team){
       this.team = team;
    }
}
```

And the way I'm testing this out is to go to my url and add ?team=123 to the end.  I'm expecting `System.out` to print `123`.  Any ideas on how to fix this error?

Answer (score 3):

I figuered it out... I forgot to include:

```
  public Long getTeam(){
     return team;
  }
```